# How to parse a string with key-value pairs separated by spaces?

Tags: python, regex, parsing, dictionary

Given a string as such:

> LexicalReordering0= -1.88359 0 -1.6864 -2.34184 -3.29584 0
>   Distortion0= -4 LM0= -85.3898 WordPenalty0= -13 PhrasePenalty0= 11
>   TranslationModel0= -6.79761 -3.06898 -8.90342 -4.35544

It contains the key of the desired dictionary that ends with `=` and until the next key, the rest of the values separated by spaces are the values of the current key.

**Do note that the name of the keys are not know before parsing the input string**

The resulting dictionary should look like this:

> {'PhrasePenalty0=': [11.0], 'Distortion0=': [-4.0],
>   'TranslationModel0=': [-6.79761, -3.06898, -8.90342, -4.35544],
>   'LM0=': [-85.3898], 'WordPenalty0=': [-13.0], 'LexicalReordering0=':
>   [-1.88359, 0.0, -1.6864, -2.34184, -3.29584, 0.0]}

I could do so with this loop:

```
>>> textin ="LexicalReordering0= -1.88359 0 -1.6864 -2.34184 -3.29584 0 Distortion0= -4 LM0= -85.3898 WordPenalty0= -13 PhrasePenalty0= 11 TranslationModel0= -6.79761 -3.06898 -8.90342 -4.35544"
>>> thiskey = ""
>>> thismap = {}
>>> for element in textin.split():
...     if element[-1] == '=':
...             thiskey = element
...             thismap[thiskey] = []
...     else:
...             thismap[thiskey].append(float(element))
... 
>>> map
{'PhrasePenalty0=': [11.0], 'Distortion0=': [-4.0], 'TranslationModel0=': [-6.79761, -3.06898, -8.90342, -4.35544], 'LM0=': [-85.3898], 'WordPenalty0=': [-13.0], 'LexicalReordering0=': [-1.88359, 0.0, -1.6864, -2.34184, -3.29584, 0.0]}
```

But **is there another way to achieve the same dictionary from the input string?** (maybe regex or some pythonic parser library?).

Comment: Basically you need to split input string by regex - '\S+='

Comment: `map` is a builtin, so you shouldn't use it as a variable name.

Comment: @rici, thanks for the note!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a way to do it using the regular expression library. I don't know if it is more efficient, or even if it could be described as pythonic:

```
pat = re.compile(r'''([^\s=]+)=\s*((?:[^\s=]+(?:\s|$))*)''')

# The values are lists of strings
entries = dict((k, v.split()) for k, v in pat.findall(textin))

# Alternative if you want the values to be floating point numbers
entries = dict((k, list(map(float, v.split())))
               for k, v in pat.findall(textin))
```

In Python 2.x, you can use `map(float, v.split())` instead of `list(map(float, v.split)))`.

Unlike the original program, this one allows inputs where there is no whitespace between the `=` and the first value. Also, any items in the input before the first instance of `key=` are silently ignored. It might be better to explicitly recognize them and throw an error.

Explanation of the pattern:

```
([^\s=]+)                            A key (any non-whitespace except =)
         =\s*                        followed by = and possible whitespace
             ((?:[^\s=]+(?:\s|$))*)  Any number of repetitions of a string
                                     without = followed by either whitespace
                                     or the end of the input
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your input string is separated by spaces and you either have keys or values, you can use split() and then loop through the elements and assign them.

```
entries = textin.split()
key = ""
for x in entries:
    try:
        x = float(x)
        answer[key].append(x)
    except ValueError:
        key = x[:-1] # ignore last char '='
        answer[key] = []
```

I am assuming that the first element of your string will always be a key, so `answer[key]` will never get called when `key` is an empty string.